# How to publish all the images from tridion environment to a particular path of folder structure?

Tags: publishing

when we click on a image it redirects to some url of folder structure where these images are not published so i need to publish those images to that place.

Answer (score 4):

There could be a few reasons for this, but the most likely one is that in your publication properties (in the Tridion GUI right click the publication and select Properties) the Images path and Images URL are not aligned with the root location that your publication is publishing into. Check these settings make sense.
Typically you would have

- Images Path: /something/images
- Images URL: /images

And your website root would be the folder 'something'.

You could also check the cd_storage_conf.xml file on your deployer and web application to make sure that the storage settings are identical, and the publication is publishing to the correct root folder.